# Modify "Source:" link text created by Facebook Comments social plugin, to your Profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

The Facebook [Comments social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments)  can take the comment you post to its host page and post it to your Profile page also (See the checkbox that enables this option in the linked sample).

While posting your comment to your Profile, the plugin appends a "Source" link to the bottom of that post. (This is common for Facebook posts because they derive from different sources like mobile, Web, Twitter, app X, service Y, Z, etc.)

That generated *Source* link on my Profile turns out ugly because it reflects the entire URL of the page that hosts the comments plugin, instead of just "web" for example.

For example, when I make the following comment on the sample host page for the plugin:

```
John K            1:43 pm
This is my comment!
[Delete]
```

the corresponding post to my personal Profile looks like this (see specifically the Source: link text)

```
John K

This is my comment!

Comments - Facebook Developers
Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments
6 minutes ago via Developer Site · [icon] · Like · Comment
```

**How can I customize the 'Source:' link text or get rid of it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe the URL attribute to set the source URL. For further info check this page - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_%28XFBML%29